# Preserving React DOM elements' native state during a transplant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-input

I'm working with React to create a form-like interface, you know, with various `<input/>` elements and such. One of the features is that the text fields will arrange and rearrange themselves due to other data (from the server or other inputs)...

React handles all the shifting okay, *except for one case*: moving an element between parents.

My `render()` JSX may switch between the following depending on the state:

```
return (
    <div className="parent">
        <h4>Before container</h4>

        <input type="text" key="one"/>
        <div className="container"/>
    </div>
)
```

And:

```
return (
    <div className="parent">
        <h4>After container</h4>

        <div className="container"/>
        <input type="text" key="one"/>
    </div>
)
```

That all works just fine—the input is moved around and keeps all its browser-native state (focus/currently-entered text/selection/etc).

But when it switches to:

```
return (
    <div className="parent">
        <h4>Inside container</h4>

        <div className="container">
            <input type="text" key="one"/>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

It re-creates the `<input/>` DOM element from scratch and all its browser-native state is lost, despite keeping the `key=` intact!

**Here's [a codepen](https://codepen.io/robbiewxyz/pen/MEjWLj?editors=0011)** demonstrating what goes wrong. Your typing stays intact moving between "before" and "after", but dies on "inside".

---

Is this a fundamental limitation of React, or is there a proper way to keep a native element intact while moving between parents?

Answer (score 1):

The `key` prop is meant to differentiate between peer components.  It is assumed that components in different contexts are not comparable.  For instance,

```
<div className="parent">
    <h4>Before and After container</h4>

    <input type="text" key="one"/>
    <div className="container"/>
    <input type="text" key="one"/>
</div>
```

Will cause problems, but;

```
<div className="parent">
    <h4>Before and Inside container</h4>

    <input type="text" key="one"/>
    <div className="container">
        <input type="text" key="one"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

will be fine.

So how do we solve the problem?

Your best bet is to assign a ref to the input field and then re-focus it after each update;

```
<input type="text" key="one" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}/>
```

and then

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.textInput.focus();
}
```

updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGdmeV

EDIT:

Given that you really need the native support due to your other tools, a better method might be just to enforce consistent hierarchy;

```
<div className="parent">
    <h4>Before container</h4>
    <div key="oneContainer">
        <input type="text" key="one"/>
    </div>
    <div className="container"/>
</div>


<div className="parent">
    <h4>After container</h4>
    <div className="container"/>
    <div key="oneContainer">
        <input type="text" key="one"/>
    </div>
</div>



<div className="parent">
    <h4>Inside container</h4>
    <div className="container" key="oneContainer">
        <input type="text" key="one"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bowNKB

Comment: Gah, crumb! This `.focus` trick does its job... but not really. It kills the touch keyboard on mobile, loses the user's exact selection, and resets any third party (non-react) tools using the input. *If this is really the best React can do, color me disappointed.* :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is right,  when you put the input element in a new container, react creates a new virtual DOM node and rerenders its children. When you simply put a bunch of  elements at the same depths, react keeps track of the order of each element based on key prop and only reorder element without a complete rerender. Though I have no idea why you want to put an element in a container when reoder them, you could store the state in the component's state and pass it accordingly. If the state somehow can not be saved to state. You chould find a common hierarchy to the elements, for example, wrap every input in a container and assign key to the containers instead of inputs.